# Image center, not background css or negative margin

Tags: css, image, background, height, width

I have a  with an image inside it can not be in the background of the div css. It is 3000px wide, the div must occupy 100% of the resolution of the user and need to focus the image.

Now it is painted correctly cut the image inside the div to 100% width * height 504px. However, I need to focus the image, because now comes attached to the left and above the div.

How I can make the image is centered? It can not be by CSS background or negative margins because the resolution of each user is different and not for a fixed width is just 100%.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS please?

Comment: css/html or jsfiddle appreciate.

Comment: I use the image in bg so I could fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your css style,

It may be useful to you

```
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
```

Comment: Wasn't useful with a image that have to pass the resolution of the screen. I used bg, thx for all!